# Making a file by running open or anything else can we protect it with password

Tags: python, file, password-protection

I wrote a program it runs asking user a password and a file name and data and then i make a file in txt format but it can be changed or can be deleted by the user or by anyone else having the device in which the file was made by going in the path where i stored it. So, Can I make a file which can't be changed or accessed by the user without knowing password or something else somewhat i want that it can be least or not accessable by the user.Can you tell me the format of file which i should make to do so.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

1. Making file inaccessible is about file ownership & permissions: if you are on linux, read about `chmod` and `chown`
2. Telling whether someone modified the file -- read about Signing & Verification - e.g. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing
3. Preventing someone from understanding the content, having access to it -- read about Encryption - https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#encryption